How to always get a merge conflict for certain files?
How do I make git merge to always raise a conflict for a specific file while merging from main branch to feature-branch?
In .git/config file, I have defined the following:
    [merge "alwaysConflict"]
            name = Always Conflict Merge Driver
            driver = false


and in .gitattributes file I have defined the following
    relative/path/to/specific/file merge=alwaysConflict


I expected that with this configuration, when I merge from main branch to feature-branch, this will always show up merge conflicts for the the file I specified above, however any change that I made to this file in main branch are just merged by git, without raising any conflict.
How can I ensure that git always raises a merge conflict in this scenario, irrespective of the changes made in the file?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35493374/7976758 "Custom merge drivers are run whenever a 3-way merge is needed, i.e. whenever a file has changed in both merge parents since the merge base."

@phd - Thanks for the comment, yes indeed once I committed the file in feature branch once, then the merge from main branch always shows up as a merge conflict.

Now that you know you need changes in both branches in order for the merge conflict to occur, perhaps this question can be closed now? (Maybe marked as not reproducible or due to a typo?)

@Santhosh Yes but did you make a commit changing the file in both branches?
